# getting (" placeholder ") input attribute in django

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to get my *placeholder input attribute*, when a user submit the form. How can it be done in django framework?
for example,
I want it to be done like this:

```
    def get_attr(request):
        plh = request.POST.get('placeholder')
```

I know that the code above isn't correct, because the POST method doesn't have that attribute.
So, what can I do?

Comment: You cannot do this, and this has nothing to do with Django. Placeholders are not submitted by the browser, by definition. Why would you want this?

Comment: I want that, because I need the placeholder and the value submitted, I have to do something whit these two data in backend

Comment: That didn't help at all. Why specifically do you need to get it from the submission? Presumably your code is responsible for creating the form in the first place, so it already knows what the placeholder is.

Comment: no, the placeholder attr is generated in template by {{ i.j }}.

Comment: Yes. And what are `i` and `j`? They're the form and field *defined in your code*.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Django, you can user JS for getting placeholder easily.

Assign a ID to your input field

Using JavaScript

> document.getElementById("demo").placeholder

Using Jquery

> $('#weight').attr('placeholder')

Then you can use this value in any way you want to